# How should the bhakti of god be done?

Tags: bhakti

How should we do bhakti of god ? Should we continously keep chanting the name of god in whatever free time we have ?

In what way bhakti of god should be pursued ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given below some tips from Srimad Bhagavata Purana.

**Prahlada’s nine points of devotion**

> Hearing about Vishnu, singing about Him, remembering Him, serving Him,
> saluting Him, being His servant, being His comrade, and surrendering
> oneself and everything that is one’s own to Him – these are the nine
> aspects of Bhakti or God-love. If man could be trained to practice
> devotion characterized by these nine features that indeed would be the
> highest education he could have.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana VII.5.23-24**

**Serving Others with love**

> I abide in all beings as their inner-most soul. Disregarding My
> presence within them, men make a show of worshiping Me through images.
> If one disregards Me present in all as their soul and Lord but
> ignorantly offers worship only to images, such worship is as
> ineffective as a sacrificial offering made in ashes. A man who
> persecutes Me residing in others, who is proud and haughty, who looks
> upon God as the other – such a person will never attain to peace of
> mind. If a man disregards and persecutes fellow beings, but worships
> Me in images with numerous rituals and rich offerings, I am not at all
> pleased with him for proffering such worship. **A man should, however,
> worship Me in images, side by side with discharging his duties, which
> include the love of all beings, until he actually realizes My presence
> in in himself and in all beings. As long as man is self-centered and
> makes an absolute distinction between himself and others (without
> recognising the unity of all in Me, the Inner Pervader), he will be
> subject to the great fear of Death (including every form of
> deprivation of self-interest). So, overcoming the separateness of a
> self-centered life, one should serve all beings with gifts, honor and
> love, recognizing that such service is really being rendered to Me who
> reside in all beings as their innermost soul.**

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.29.21-27**

**Definition of Bhakti**

> When all the powers of man’s senses, which are ordinarily frittered
> away through external contacts, are purified through devotional
> practices and dedicated action, and they get naturally focused on
> Isvara (Sattva) exclusively, without any extraneous and self-centered
> motivation, and with a firmness which an obstruction can overpower –
> that state of mind is called Bhakti, or the highest form of devotion
> for the Lord. Such devotion is superior even to Mukti. It burns up the
> covering of ignorance in a person just as fire burns up objects put
> into it. Some endowed with such Bhakti do not aspire for Moksha or
> even oneness with My being.; for their delight consists in serving Me
> and in working out My will. They therefore congregate together and
> honor Me by adoration and participation in My works.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.25.32-34**