# Are wrong things also done by god?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, advaita, bhagavata-purana

[Here it is written](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58133/23709) that god pervades in all. So, Does this mean wrong and evil things are also done by god ?

It is also written that we should see god in everyone,so, Should we see god even in persons who are engaged in committing evil things.

Comment: God pervades all means, the basis of the existence of everything is God. All good, evil, ghosts, gods, everything is made up of god. Just as a bracelet, bangle, ring, all are made up of metal, irrespective of shape, similarly, all good, evil, ghosts, gods, right, wrong are made up of god.

Answer (score 1):

> So, Does this mean wrong and evil things are also done by god ?

In A way, yes. Since All that is 'Good' and 'bad' are vibhutis of God only.

> **द्यूतं छलयतामस्मि तेजस्तेजस्विनामहम् | जयोऽस्मि व्यवसायोऽस्मि सत्त्वं सत्त्ववतामहम् || 36||**
>
> **I am the gambling of the cheats** and the splendor of the splendid. I am the victory of the victorious, the resolve of the resolute, and
> the virtue of the virtuous.

~ BhagavadGita 10.36

This is Why in the Sri Rudram of Yajur veda, we find God being glorified even through thieves, plunderers, robbers thus signifying his omnipresence.

> **21. Homage to the cheat, to the arch-deceiver, to the Lord of stealers homage! Homage to the wearer of sword and quiver, to the Lord of
> robbers homage! Homage to the boltarmed homicides, to the Lord of
> pilferers homage! Homage to the sword-bearers, to those who roam at
> night, to the Lord of plunderers homage!**
>
> **22.** **To the turban-wearing haunter of mountains, Lord of land-grabbers homage!** Homage to you who bear arrows and to you who carry bows.
> Homage to you with bent bows, and to you who adjust your arrows, to
> you who draw the bow and to you who shoot be homage!

**Sri Rudram, Sukla Yajurveda, Vâjasanayi-Samhitâ, Book 16**

Comment: This is a very good answer in the context of non-dualism. Please keep contributing here in the future too.